# why wont my Gyroscope app in android fire off any events?

Tags: java, android, events, gyroscope

alright so I'm new to programming for android, and I think I did something wrong, but I don't know what. I've looked at 3 different tutorials and my code seems to look like theirs. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? here is my src (altered from a android nehe tutorial).

```
package cypri.games;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * The initial Android Activity, setting and initiating
 * the OpenGL ES Renderer Class @see Lesson02.java
 * 
 * @author Savas Ziplies (nea/INsanityDesign)
 */
public class DGearActivity extends Activity {

    /** The OpenGL View */
    private GLSurfaceView glSurface;
    DGear dGear = new DGear();

    private static final String TAG = "DEBUG";

    SensorManager sensorManager;
    private final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener(){
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
             if (se.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
                 dGear.playerX = se.values[0];
                 Log.v(TAG, "se.values[0] =" + se.values[0]);
             }
        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };

    /**
     * Initiate the OpenGL View and set our own
     * Renderer (@see Lesson02.java)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        //Create an Instance with this Activity
        glSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        //Set our own Renderer
        glSurface.setRenderer(dGear);
        //Set the GLSurface as View to this Activity
        setContentView(glSurface);
    }

    /**
     * Remember to resume the glSurface
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.v(TAG, "or");
        super.onResume();
        glSurface.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    /**
     * Also pause the glSurface
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        glSurface.onPause();
        Log.v(TAG, "op");
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorListener);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the log?  What is convincing you that it isn't working?

Comment: not seeing se.values[0] in the logcat log but I see the logs for onResume (or) and on Pause (op)

Comment: Do you need a permission to use the gyroscope, and if so, did you add it to your application manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are you running this in the emulator or on an actual device?
2. If you're running it on an actual device are you sure it has a gyroscope?  There are [lots of different sensor types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) and the gyroscope is only one of them.  It could very well be one of the others.

Instead of only writing to the log if it's a gyroscope type, try writing the name of the `se.sensor` when that event fires.  That way you'll at least know the event is firing.

Comment: I shoulda researched more. My phone doesn't have a gyroscope. I got the desired effect with a accelomeater.